# Jquery tabs elements with same id

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tabs

I am working with wordpress and jquery tabs and was wondering if somebody can help me. My example is similar to this one [jQuery UI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Here is my php code

```
<?php if (!defined('FW')) die( 'Forbidden' ); ?>
<?php $tabs_id = uniqid('fw-image-tabs-'); ?>
    <div class="fw-image-tabs-container" id="<?php echo esc_attr($tabs_id); ?>">
        <div class="fw-image-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($atts['image_tabs'] as $key => $tab) : ?>
                <div class="fw-image-tabs-content" id="<?php echo esc_attr($tabs_id . '-' . ($key + 1)); ?>">
                    <h3 class="fw-image-tabs-content"><?php echo $tab['tab_image_title']; ?></h3>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $tab['tab_image']['url']); ?>">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($atts['image_tabs'] as $key => $tab) : ?>
                    <li><a href="#<?php echo esc_attr($tabs_id . '-' . ($key + 1)); ?>"><?php echo $tab['tab_title']; ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>

            <?php foreach ( $atts['image_tabs'] as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <div class="fw-image-tabs-content" id="<?php echo esc_attr($tabs_id . '-' . ($key + 1)); ?>">
                    <p><?php echo do_shortcode( $tab['tab_content'] ) ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fw-image-tabs-container').tabs();
});
```

The trouble i am having is that i cannot hide the second `<div class="fw-image-tabs-content"></div>`. Both divs have the same class name and the same id. For some reason only the first id works. How can i show/hide the text for both divs?

Thanks

Comment: hi , you need to set the uniqueness to set the multiple tabs functionality

Comment: Multiple divs should never have the same ID

Comment: Even if i change the id of the second div it still doesn't work.

Comment: Not saying it will fix the issue, but multiple divs with the same Id makes the html invalid

Comment: instead of this $('.fw-image-tabs').tabs(); try $('.fw-image-tabs:first').tabs();$('.fw-image-tabs:last').tabs();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fw-image-tabs').tabs();
});
```